# What's your favorite SSL cert provider?

Tags: ssl, certificate

Who do you recommend for SSL certs? Digicert, Verisign, someone else? I'd like someone with a trusted root certificate.

Answer (score 5):

GoDaddy.com

For me they are local, but the biggest advantage is 24/7 phone support

and besides the wildcard cert for *.homeserver.com was issued by GoDaddy...how many people have that one loaded up?

Answer (score 5):

I have started using [DigiCert](http://www.digicert.com/) recently because they are cheap and their wildcard certificates (again cheap) work on multiple servers at no extra cost. They also have a nice reseller program.

Comment: Their support is top-notch, as in after jumping online and chatting with them a couple times, I said "That's the kind of place I'd like to work." (No I don't work for them, or resell for them or anything.)

Their wildcard cert is a particularly good value.

Comment: +1 I am hearing them as a recommendation over Verisign more and more lately, mainly because of better pricing.  However, GoDaddy is more popular because it is super-cheap, and Verisign is still considered the best-of-the-best, if you have the cash to spare.

Answer (score 2):

[Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/) used them for years - they are absolutely the best out there. I only used one other (can't remember the name) because I needed a special type of certificate for an Exchange deployment that Thawte did not offer.

Comment: Thawte is also owned by Verisign, which should assuage any concerns about them as a CA.  In rare circumstances I have encountered a situation where the Thawte CA was not trusted, but installation of their root certificate resolved that issue.

Comment: Most Thawte certificates now require a CA chaining certificate nowadays.  This can be a challenge in mixed server-type environments.

Answer (score 1):

I've used most of them and they mostly vary in service.

FWIW, RapidSSL has worked out fine for me.

Comment: FYI, it's not always advertised but Thwate is owned by Verisign.

Answer (score 0):

The root certificate list has ballooned so large over the past few years that certificates signed by a "trusted" root authority are affordable and relatively easy to come by.  I believe there are over 200 root authorities now, including everything from Verisign to the Hong Kong Post Office.

I've used GoDaddy in the past. Their certs are affordable and well recognized.

Answer (score 0):

We use verisign here at the office.

Answer (score 0):

I use two; instantssl for my mail server and geotrust (owned by versign) for a public facing site.

For a while instantssl required an intermediate certificate, and have managed to get their mail server blacklisted by sorbs for spamming, so I wouldn't recommend them.

Answer (score 0):

At the office we use Entrust and it's been great.  Their certificate management is extremely slick.  I used to use Geotrust at an old job, before they were part of Verisign, and they were OK too.

Answer (score 0):

I like GoDaddy, the process was quick and easy. They have good online documentation once you login. The price was right (mix in a discount from buying another product, or use the discount from buying this to renew a domain and things are even cheaper).

I just bought a domain and the certificate had two names in it, www.domainname.com and domainname.com for the price of one domain (no more need to buy two or use redirection).